# JPCAP: Trying to extract the payload data but getTCPData() method is missing

Tags: java, network-programming, ubuntu-16.04, jpcap, netbeans-8.1

I'm using Jpcap ver.0.7 (Keita Fujii) library on Ubuntu 16.04 X86 and I'm trying to extract packet payload data using `getTCPData()` but the method is missing.

This is my code

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import jpcap.PacketReceiver;
import jpcap.packet.ICMPPacket;
import jpcap.packet.IPPacket;
import jpcap.packet.Packet;
import jpcap.packet.TCPPacket;
import jpcap.packet.UDPPacket;

class PacketPrinter implements PacketReceiver, PacketListener {
    //this method is called every time Jpcap captures a packet


@Override
public void receivePacket(Packet packet) {
    if (packet instanceof TCPPacket) {
        TCPPacket pac = (TCPPacket) packet;
        byte[] data;
        data = pac.getTCPData();

        System.out.println("TCP ~~ Src: " + pac.src_ip + " Dest: " + pac.dst_ip + " dest port : " + pac.dst_port + " src port : " + pac.src_port);

    } else if (packet instanceof UDPPacket) {
        UDPPacket pac = (UDPPacket) packet;
        pac.
        System.out.println("UDP ~~ Src: " + pac.src_ip + " Dest: " + pac.dst_ip + " dest port : " + pac.dst_port + " src port : " + pac.src_port);

    } else if (packet instanceof ICMPPacket) {
        ICMPPacket pac = (ICMPPacket) packet;
        System.out.println("ICMP ~~ Src: " + pac.src_ip + " Dest: " + pac.dst_ip);

    } else if (packet instanceof IPPacket) {
        IPPacket pac = (IPPacket) packet;
        System.out.println("IP ~~ Src: " + pac.src_ip + " Dest: " + pac.dst_ip);

    }
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are two similar projects with the same name:

- Jpcap by Keita Fujii
- Jpcap on sourceforge

They are independently developed and I'm using the first one ,that's why this method is missing.
 Jpcap on sourceforge has more features.